# How to add an admin function only to posts, not pages?

Tags: posts, functions, admin, excerpt

I'm having a problem with adding an excerpt counter to the excerpt field.  It may be a conflict with another plugin, but basically it screws with other jquery if the excerpt field doesn't exist (e.g.: when it's a page which doesn't have an excerpt).

Some issues that occur are: kills admin nav fly-out, media button doesn't work...

Is there a conditional I could use that would only add this function if it is a post, or if it has the excerpt field?  I have several custom post types, and the default posts all using the excerpt field.

Here is the code I have so far, but I can't figure out what conditional would make this work:

```
function excerpt_count_js(){
    if(possible_conditional_here()) {
          echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:0px;right:5px;color:#666;\"><small>Character limit = 150. Current characters: </small><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"excerpt_counter\" readonly=\"\" style=\"background:#fff;\">&nbsp;</div>");
         jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
         jQuery("#excerpt").keyup( function() {
         jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
       });
    });</script>';
      }
      return;
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
```

I've tried these (none of which worked):

`if(post_type_exists())` - doesn't display at all
`if(!is_page())` - doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you checked the console for any javascript errors?

Comment: Yes - when/because there is no excerpt field:  >jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use post type conditional tag:

```
if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
```

Complete:

```
function excerpt_count_js(){
    if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
          echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:0px;right:5px;color:#666;\"><small>Character limit = 150. Current characters: </small><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"excerpt_counter\" readonly=\"\" style=\"background:#fff;\">&nbsp;</div>");
         jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
         jQuery("#excerpt").keyup( function() {
         jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
       });
    });</script>';
      }
      return;
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
```

Comment: I think they want `'page' != get_post_type()` to add it on all post types except page.

Comment: Rafael thanks so much - works perfectly and no more errors!!!